# Framework for both: web & standalone application

Tags: c++, qt, frameworks

Dear everyone, I am just curious, is it possible to create standalone GUI application which further can be easily migrated to the web? Or, even better, will be able to work in two modes locally and remotely through web browser. Since the main application logic is already written on C++ I read a little about Qt Quick. As I understood it is somehow possible to mix web application and standalone one, but I haven't found direct example illustrating the case I am interested in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your application does. If it is heavy UI bound and not calculation intense you will not get very far with Qt. There are a few toolkits for Java like GWT which help you to program an AJAX app like you would program a normal desktop GUI - but i don't know any C++ framework doing the same.

For a non heavy UI bound application i would convert the UI to HTML5 and just deploy the webserver infrastructure with your application and a self written Browser based on QT. With this it is trivial to switch between local and remote apps.

For a heavy UI bound application, use GWT.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get your statement about Qt. I've heard about GWT we will possibly use it if I don't find anything for C++. If nothing change my mind I will choose standalone webserver + Qt based browser.

Comment: I meant that if you use Qt for the local application (real Qt GUI not just a Qt based webbrowser with some convenient GUI operations - like customized main menu bars) then you have to duplicate the UI code for local and remote application. Qt widgets other then QtWebView do not offer any way to be controlled from a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your back in terms of services, then your stand-alone and web front ends can both use them.  That lets you have multiple user interfaces without affecting the processing.  Easy to add mobile, too.